# what do "^+CHAR" commands on Unix (^C stops the current command, for example) do?

Tags: linux, unix, command

For example when I run something like `nc localhost 8000` and then I press ctrl+C it writes "^C" and it stops the connection. How are these "^ commands" called and where can I find what other ctrl+CHAR (or ^+CHAR) do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [UNIX.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not commands but control chars. They are chars as other chars are but have special meanings in some contexts. When using command line interface (shell in a terminal) for instance, every typed char passes through a special software piece that captures some chars and associates them to some functionality. You must know that all of this can be modified/parametrized but in general you can use:

- ^S/^Q to control the flow
- ^C to kill the current process
- ^D to terminate the input flow
- ^Z to suspend the current process
- ^H to erase the last character (same has *backspace*)
- ^U to erase the whole current line

This list is not exhaustive... Be aware that some other characters may have a meaning in the software you are using; I mean even the shell itself can associated some functionality to some chars.

Try `stty -a` to observe what is activated and what are the chars (if needed) associated to which functionality. Then read the manual about this command and a book about POSIX terminals (the name of a software piece I talked about formerly). Also read shell's manual.